# Is there a way in IntelliJ to make a usage search of a method and filter this by specific arguments passed to the method?

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, structural-search

I have a method in my Service class which executes an hibernate update for any domain object:

```
update(Object obj)
```

It's called from lot's of classes in my project for different kind of objects. I would like to find all usages of this method when it's called for a specific domain object. I.e. call methods call wich executes an update of my Title object:

```
serviceClass.update(Title title)
```

I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE and I'm wondering if there is a way to find all those usages.
Does anyone have an IDEA how to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Ronny

Comment: Did you try the [SSR](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Basics_of_working_with_structural_search)?

Comment: cool, thanks for that hint! I tried to make a suitable search template, but I could find any solution for make an `instance of` test on the method parameter. I need to do it because the method could be called like `objectDAO.update(t)` or `objectDAO.update(title)` or any other parameter naming one of our programmers just had in mind... Any Idea how I could handle this?

Comment: Try the `method calls` existing template and modify it [like this](http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/2333/20121019170202.png).

Comment: actually I thought this is exactly what I'm looking for, but it doesn't work in may case. The signature of the method is `void update(Object obj)` and if I filter the parameter type as you told with a specific type `Title` no occurences are found. If I filter by type `Object` all occurences are found :( seems like SSR is not smart enough to evalute the type before it's casted to Object...

Comment: it's smart enough, but I was wrong with the option, use **java expression type** instead of **formal argument type**.

Comment: thanks you, the **java expression type** did the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried it with a small sample project and was able to achieve the desired behavior using [Structural Search and Replace](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Basics_of_working_with_structural_search) feature with the modified `method calls` template:

[image]

`$MethodCall$` **Text constraints**, **Text/regexp** should be set to `update` so that methods with other names are ignored. `$Parameter$` **Occurrences count**, **Minimum count** should be set to `1` to ignore method calls with no or more parameters.

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: I also added a **text constraint** _update_ for the variable $MethodCall$ do get only update methods which are called with title. For some reason I also get some update() methods with emtpy args, but just a few so I can live with that...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll update the answer. If you set parameter minimum count to 1, it will not match method calls without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the call chains that are providing a specific input into a given method, try the *Analyze->Data Flow to Here* command.

This allows you to see which values are passed in, through which call chains. And, for example, where *null* values might be coming from.

Quite a powerful feature, really.